# Using Select query, nothing merges onto Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a Crystal template that I am modifying in developer because we are changing the datasource from an Access file to our Oracle DB. I created a database field that accurately connects to Oracle and added a select statement that because pulls a field from a particular table

```
select s.field from table s;
```

On the right hand side, under database fields, I see my command and can right click and browse the data, which right now returns two values.

I also made a formula field using an Azalea barcode function that calls the values (I think, this is where stuff is going wrong, I guess)

The formula field is

```
BarcodeC39ASCII({Command.field})
```

So this should take the data and format it into the barcode, except when I use print preview or print out the report, no data is merged.

I've tested this by creating a new formula field with just the Command.field, and still no data is merged. I imagine there is something *really* obvious that I am missing and would appreciate any input.

Comment: I think because I am selecting the entire column, I may need to create a subreport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unless I misunderstood your question, you are changing your datasource from Access DB to Oracle DB, correct? Assuming that the database structure remains the same then all you should need to do is go into Database -> Set Datasource Location and set the datasource location from the Access DB to the Oracle DB and your existing report should work as it did. You might have to map some fields, but that should be the extend of it. Is that what you are trying to do?

Chris

Comment: Pretty much. I created the new datasource using an ODBC and created a 'command' to select the data I wanted, so the table name changed from Subject.field to Command.field (I updated the function to reflect this change). - The only difference is now no data is merging. I haven't figured out how to do this with a subreport. The idea was that each report should pull one value from the table.column

Comment: In my opinion all you should have to do is to use the original report you have (the one that was using the Access DB) and change the datasource from the current Access datasource to the new Oracle datasource. If any fields can't automatically be mapped you will be prompted to manually map them. You use the steps I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thats what I think too but something is wrong. I will accept your answer anyway because I'm abandoning the SAP Java Runtime Libraries for a different reporting tool such as BIRT or Jasper.......Down with crystal

Comment: Jackie, sorry that it didn't work out for you. Hopefully you have better luck with the other report tools.